# How to animate scrolling from current scroll position to target scroll position with help of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have scroll animation for my block. The block should scroll from current scroll position of the `page(page_scroll_value)` to target scroll position `(my_scroll_value)`.

I know about `.animate()` method in jQuery but I didn't find something about animation from value A to value B. How I can solve the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one example

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/n1xtsx42/15/)

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': 0 // or any specific offset postion
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question right, this will work:

```
$("#element").animate({scrollTop: my_scroll_value}, 500);
```

where 100 is the duration in milliseconds.